# InputMultiplexer working only on a Stage

Tags: android, input, libgdx

I have a `libGDX` project, in which I would like to use multiple inputprocessors. `im` is `InputMultiplexer`, `stage` and `dialog` are `Stages`. `InputController` and `dialog` named `Stage` is working perfectly, but `ImageButton` type `Actors` on `stage` aren't working, can't do any action after clicking.

```
im.addProcessor(stage);
im.addProcessor(inputController);
im.addProcessor(dialog);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
```

What should maybe cause this problem, what should I check?

Comment: How do you implement click() event on these ImageButtons? Please show  your code

Comment: With InputMultiplexer it is important how you deal with eventProcessed and the issue might be there, but as stated in comment above you need to show more code, otherwise it's impossible to tell anything.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong: Thanks, problem was with event handling, with use of `ChangeListener()` it is working.

Comment: Since my comment was helpful I made an answer out of it. If you don't mind please accept it, so this question doesn't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with InputMultiplexer this kind of issues often occur when event processing is handled incorrectly, so it's the first thing to check.